# display value from reactiveVar meteor

Tags: meteor, reactive

In meteor, how can one insert and display value using a reactiveVar.
I need to store and display an object.

Set Value

```
this.test = new ReactiveVar({});
let temp = {};
_.each(usms, function(usm){
    Meteor.call(functionName, parameterPassed, function(err, res){
        if(!err)
            this.test.set([parameterPassed] = res);
    });
});
```

Display Value

```
return Template.instance().test.get([paraMeterPassed]);
```

Basically this is how I want  to store data :
{id : value,
 id2 : value2
}

For now, I am using an extra variable to achieve this which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here if you want to avoid to use a second variable.

#### First option

First option is to use `reactive-dict` package, which is an exact key-value mapping of reactive variables. This would work like the following:

```js
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict';

// ...

this.state = new ReactiveDict({});

_.each(usms, function(usm){
    Meteor.call(functionName, parameterPassed, function(err, res){
        if(!err)
            this.state.set(parameterPassed, res);
    });
});
```

where I assume, that `parameterPassed` is some kind of your key. You can then return the value by

return Template.instance().state.get(paraMeterPassed);

Note, that the `ReactiveDict` can store as many reactive values as you want and I gave it therefore the name `state`. You can of course name it whatever you want.

#### Second option

If you want to stick with `ReactiveVar` you won't get around of retrieving the current value:

```js
const instance = this;
instance.test = new ReactiveVar({});

_.each(usms, function(usm){
    Meteor.call(functionName, parameterPassed, (err, res) => {
        if(!err) {
            const test = instance.test.get();
            test[parameterPassed] = res;
            instance.test.set(test);
        }
    });
});
```

But you can use a function that wraps up this for:

```js
const instance = this;
instance.test = new ReactiveVar({});

instance.setTest = function(key, value) {
    const dict = instance.test.get();
    dict[key] = value;
    instance.test.set(dict);
};

instance.getTest = function(name) {
    const dict  = instance.test.get();
    return dict[name];
}

// ...

_.each(usms, function(usm){
    Meteor.call(functionName, parameterPassed, (err, res) => {
        if(!err) {
            instance.setTest(parameterPassed, res);
        }
    });
});

// ...

return Template.instance().getTest(paraMeterPassed);
```

I personally use the `ReactiveDict` when I have more complex data to deal with, while `ReactiveVar` comes in handy when dealing with simple data.